# Count sub-sequences of an array having median lying in that subsequence itself

Tags: c++, algorithm, array, statistics

We need to calculate the number of sub-sequences of an array having its median lying in the sub-sequence itself. My code is -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 


#define MOD 1000000007
#define fori0n for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define inputLoop for(int j=0;j<t;j++)

// FAST SCANNING .. 
template<typename T> void scan(T &x) 
{ 
     x = 0; 
     bool neg = 0; 
     register T c = getchar(); 

     if (c == '-') 
     neg = 1, c = getchar(); 

     while ((c < 48) || (c > 57)) 
     c = getchar(); 

     for ( ; c < 48||c > 57 ; c = getchar()); 

     for ( ; c > 47 && c < 58; c = getchar() ) 
             x= (x << 3) + ( x << 1 ) + ( c & 15 ); 

      if (neg) x *= -1; 
}



// FAST PRINTING.. 
template<typename T> void print(T n) 
{ 
     bool neg = 0; 

     if (n < 0) 
     n *= -1, neg = 1; 

     char snum[65]; 
     int i = 0; 
     do
     { 
          snum[i++] = n % 10 + '0'; 
          n /= 10; 
     } 

     while (n); 
     --i; 

     if (neg) 
       putchar('-'); 

     while (i >= 0) 
         putchar(snum[i--]); 

     putchar('\n'); 
} 







float median(vector<int> new_array, int num){
       sort(new_array.begin(), new_array.end());
       float median = (num % 2 != 0) ? (new_array[((num+1)/2)-1]) : (float)(new_array[(num/2)-1] + new_array[num/2]) / 2;
      return median;
}

void subsetsUtil(vector<int>& A, vector<vector<int> >& res, 
            vector<int>& subset, int index) 
{ 
for (int i = index; i < A.size(); i++) { 

    // include the A[i] in subset. 
    subset.push_back(A[i]); 
    res.push_back(subset); 

    // move onto the next element. 
    subsetsUtil(A, res, subset, i + 1); 

    subset.pop_back(); 
} 

return; 
} 


vector<vector<int> > subsets(vector<int>& A) 
{ 
    vector<int> subset; 
    vector<vector<int> > res; 

    // include the null element in the set. 
    //res.push_back(subset); 

    // keeps track of current element in vector A; 
    int index = 0; 
    subsetsUtil(A, res, subset, index); 

   return res; 
} 


int main() 
{ 

//ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
//cin.tie(NULL);



int t;
scan(t);
//cin>>t;
inputLoop {
int n;
scan(n);
//cin>>n;

// find the subsets of below vector. 
vector<int> arr; 

int input;
fori0n {
    //cin>>input;
    scan(input);
    arr.push_back(input);
}

vector<vector<int> > res = subsets(arr); 
int goodMedian = 0;
// Print result 
for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) { 



    //cout<<"Sub set : "<<i<<" _ With Size :  "<<res[i].size()<<" == ";


    // if size == 1 or 3 
    if(res[i].size() % 2 != 0) {
        // there will always be a good median 
        //cout<<"GOOD MEDIAN ";
        goodMedian++;
    }
    else if(res[i].size() == 2) {
        if(median(res[i], 2) == res[i][0] || median(res[i], 2) == res[i][1]) {
            //cout<<"GOOD MEDIAN ";
            goodMedian++;
        }
    }
    else if(res[i].size() % 2 == 0) {
        int size = res[i].size();
        if(median(res[i], res[i].size()) == res[i][size / 2] || median(res[i], res[i].size()) == res[i][(size - 1)/2]) {
            //cout<<"GOOD MEDIAN ";
            goodMedian++;
        }
    }



    //for (int j = 0; j < res[i].size(); j++) 
    //  cout << res[i][j] << " "; 
    //cout << endl;

}
      print(goodMedian % MOD);
    }
   return 0; 
}
```

Can anyone suggest any better algorithm for this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

- Don't `#include  <bits/stdc++.h>` but explicitly include proper requested headers.
- Try to limite uses of `using namespace std;`, it lead to painfull errors and weird bug.
- Don't use preprocessor constants. Instead, use `const` and `constexpr` values.
- Don't use macro, write directly code or use (inline) (constexpr) function  if you use the same code at much places.
- Try to return value instead of taking an input reference.
- Avoid old array in favour of `std::array`.
- Don't use `register` keyword in c++
- Don't assign `1` or `0` to a `bool`, use `true` and `false` instead.
- getchar return int, why trying to convert to T.
- Try to use C++ `iostream` instead of `getchar` or `putchar`
- Instead of magical values, use const char (eg `'A'`) to express chars bound..
- Use curly braces for your statement
- Don't try to be smart putting many statement on the same line, separated by comma. It's not.
- The expression `n *= -1` can by simplified in `n = -n`
- Don't use for loops if you don't want Initialization+Condition+Operation. It's ugly.
- Take care about indents.

Answer (score 3):

A function like this, with clearly defined inputs and outputs, is best written with the aid of **unit tests** to confirm its correct operation.

Start by extracting the actual computation out of `main()`:

```
auto count_passing_subseqs(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > res = subsets(v); 
    // (rest of implementation...)

    return goodMedian % MOD;
}
```

---

Now we can write our first test.  The empty sequence has no subsequences at all, so let's check that:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(count, emptyInput)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(0, count_passing_subseqs({}));
}
```

---

That passes; good.  We can add the next most simple cases, with just one or two elements in input:

```
TEST(count, oneInput)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, count_passing_subseqs({1}));
}

TEST(count, twoSmallSame)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(3, count_passing_subseqs({1, 1}));
}

TEST(count, twoSmallDifferent)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(2, count_passing_subseqs({1, 2}));
}
```

---

Let's try some larger values, still in a small array:

```
TEST(count, twoLargeSame)
{
    auto constexpr m = INT_MAX;
    EXPECT_EQ(3, count_passing_subseqs({m, m}));
}

TEST(count, twoLargeDifferent)
{
    auto constexpr m = INT_MAX / 3;
    EXPECT_EQ(2, count_passing_subseqs({m, m-1}));
}
```

That gives us some lovely juicy bugs to fix:

```
[ RUN      ] count.twoLargeSame
207153.cpp:177: Failure
      Expected: 3
To be equal to: count_passing_subseqs({m, m})
      Which is: 2
[  FAILED  ] count.twoLargeSame (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] count.twoLargeDifferent
207153.cpp:183: Failure
      Expected: 2
To be equal to: count_passing_subseqs({m, m-1})
      Which is: 3
[  FAILED  ] count.twoLargeDifferent (0 ms)
```

One of those is due to integer overflow in `(float)(new_array[(num/2)-1] + new_array[num/2]) / 2`; the other is due to the limited precision of `float`.

---

Once we have fixed those bugs, we can move on to longer sequences.  If we have an *n*-element array with all members equal, every subarray must contain its median.  If we have an *n*-element array with all members different, only the odd-length subarrays will contain their medians.

```
// modular exponentiation - base ** exponent % reduction
static constexpr auto expmod(std::size_t base, std::size_t exponent, std::size_t reduction)
{
    std::size_t i = base;
    std::size_t result = 1;
    while (exponent) {
        if (exponent % 2) {
            result *= i;
        }
        i *= base;              // ignore risk of overflow here
        i %= reduction;
        base *= base;           // and here
        base %= reduction;
        exponent /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}

TEST(count, ManySame)
{
    static constexpr std::size_t length = 1000;
    static auto const v = std::vector<int>(length, 4);
    auto constexpr expected = expmod(2, length, MOD) - 1;
    EXPECT_EQ(expected, count_passing_subseqs(v));
}

TEST(count, ManyDifferent)
{
    static constexpr std::size_t length = 1000;
    static auto const v = []{
        std::vector<int> v(length, {});
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
        return v;
    }();
    auto constexpr expected = expmod(2, length-1, MOD);
    EXPECT_EQ(expected, count_passing_subseqs(v));
}
```

This exposes another weakness in the implementation:

```
[ RUN      ] count.ManySame
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "std::bad_alloc" thrown in the test body.
[  FAILED  ] count.ManySame (405 ms)
[ RUN      ] count.ManyDifferent
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "std::bad_alloc" thrown in the test body.
[  FAILED  ] count.ManyDifferent (408 ms)
```

This suggests that our memory use scales poorly - we need an algorithm that doesn't allocate so much extra storage.

---

I'll stop at this point, but I hope you can see how proper tests will help improve your code, and allow you to change algorithms with more confidence.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with some depressingly-common standard observations:

- `<bits/stdc++.h>` is non-standard and a bad choice for user code.
- `using namespace std;` is harmful and should be avoided
- Avoid preprocessor macros for constants or simple functions such as `std::foreach()`
- Don't use numeric character codes - that will make your code mysteriously fail on non-ASCII systems.
- Use `std::printf()` or `std::cout` instead of writing your own "fast" print function.  Don't optimize before you profile, or you'll end up wasting time on code that's a minuscule part of the run time.
- Use standard input functions, for the same reason.
- Don't copy all the subsets of input into that vector of vectors; that's a big waste of space and time.
- Don't recalculate the median for every sub-sequence; change to a more efficient algorithm (e.g. for every element (potential median), expand outwards and count how many occasions occur when the number of larger/equal elements matches the number of smaller/equal elements - you should be able to perform such a test using only integer arithmetic).
- Indent the `main()` code properly, and split it into functions that each have a clear responsibility.
- Be careful with `goodMedian++` - the variable is an `int`, which has limited range, and Undefined Behaviour on overflow.  Prefer an unsigned type, such as `std::size_t` for counting.
- Avoid comparisons between signed and unsigned integers, such as in `for (int i = index; i < A.size(); i++)`.  Just use `std::size_t i` and the bug is magically fixed.
- Don't depend on floating-point equality.  In `median(res[i], 2) == res[i][0]`, `median` returns a `float` (which likely has less precision than `int`), making that test unreliable with large values.  (In the `size==2` case, it's total overkill anyway, as you only need to test `res[i][0] == res[i][1]`.)
- Explain (in a comment) why the final result is printed modulo `MOD` (and why we ignore overflows when counting, rather than also incrementing modulo `MOD`).

Comment: If the Size of array is about 1000 so to not overflow the final answer.

Comment: I have read somewhere that the use of macros makes the execution faster.

Comment: But binding of macros is done at compilation time?

Comment: Macros get *expanded* by the preprocessor, not *bound*.  Function calls are resolved/inlined at compile-time too, so I don't know what your concern is.  Of course, any difference is completely swamped by the memory allocation and tedious recalculation - there's no point micro-optimising such trivial details when the algorithm is so inefficient.

Comment: I'm not going to simply *tell* you, since this looks like a [tag:code-challenge] and you should be prepared to do some thinking for yourself (otherwise the *challenge* is lost), but there's some hints in my review that should help.